# Haskell STM and retry

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

When we run a `STM` expression which hits `retry`, the thread is blocked and the transaction is run once again if the entries are modified.

But I was wondering :

- If we read a STM variable which, in that specific branch leading to retry, is not actually used , would updating it try to perform the transaction again ?
- While the thread is blocked, is it really blocked ? or is it recycled in a thread pool to be used by other potentially waiting operations ?

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your first question. How about providing an example? As for your second question: the thread is blocked. However Haskell threads are actually green threads by default, so many are run in one system thread. This means that other Haskell threads will still be able to do work while it is blocked.

Comment: For the 1st question : if read 2 variables but my transaction actually depends on the value of just 1

Comment: I see.. I guess green thread are efficient enough to not really care about the implementation in first approximation

Comment: For 1), I'd say yes, if you read it and retry, any modifications to it will reattempt the transition. If you do not use it, you should not read it. Or in other words, more the reads close to the use points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes. Reading STM variable will invoke stmReadTVar - see [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/STM.c). This will generate new entry in transaction record and it will be checked on commit. If you take a look [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp) you will find that ReadTVarOp marked as an operation with side effect (has_side_effects = True) so I don't think compiler will eliminate it regardless will you use it result or not.
2. As @WillSewell wrote Haskell uses green threads. You can even use STM in single-threaded runtime without worry that the actual OS thread will be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Re. 1: as I understand your question, yes that is correct; your entire STM transaction will have a consistent view of the world *including* branches composed with `orElse` (see: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8680). But I'm not sure what you mean by "but my transaction actually depends on the value of just 1 variable"; if you do a `readTVar` then changes to that var will be tracked.

Re. 2: you can think of green threads as lumps of saved computation state that are stored in a stack-like thing and popped off, run for a bit, and put back onto the stack when they can't make further progress for the time being ("blocked") or after they've run for long enough.  The degree to which this happens in parallel depends on the number of *OS threads* you tell the runtime to use (via `+RTS -N`). You can have a concurrent program that uses thousands of green threads but is only run with a single OS thread, and that's perfectly fine.